# Recursive function not being invoked in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The function clearWatchLater() is not being invoked after the timeout expires. The code inside the setTimeout() never executes.

```
const clearWatchLater = () => {
    const youtubeBaseUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com';
    if (window.location.href === youtubeBaseUrl) {
        // Do Something
    } else {
        window.focus()
        window.location.href = youtubeBaseUrl;
        setTimeout(() => {
            clearWatchLater()
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, clearWatchLater() will not be invoked.

Because When your else block gets execute you are reloading the page by using  **window.location.href = youtubeBaseUrl** .
After reloading the page Javascript call stack gets reinitialized. It will not get any previous task on its stack. SO your setTimeout is not executing.